# HK2 failure has been detected in a code that does not run in an active Jersey Error scope

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

Currently I am developing a jersey based RESTful application and would like to use DPI in my resources. 
(Note: Version of jersey is 2.23.1 and the servlet container is tomcat 8.5.3.)

Therefore I followed the tutorial [Chapter 23. Custom Injection and Lifecycle Management](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/ioc.html) in the jersey docs and created a resource, a factory and bind the factory to a class like this:

Resource:

```
@Path("/{project}/catalogs")
public class ProjectsResource {

   @Inject
   Project project;

   ...
}
```

Factory:

```
public class ProjectFactory extends Factory<Project> {

  private final Cache cache = cache.getInstance();

  @PathParam("project")
  private String project;

  private HttpServletRequest request;

  @Inject
  public ProjectFactory(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.request = request;
  }

  @Override
  public Project provide() {
    return cache.get(project, Project.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void dispose(Project instance) {}

}
```

Also I have a feature, which registers an AbstractBinder, which binds my ProjectFactory to my Project class.

```
@Provider
public class ProjectFeature implements Feature {

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {

    context.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
      bindFactory(ProjectFactory.class)
          .to(Project.class)
          .proxy(false)
          .proxyForSameScope(true)
          .in(RequestScoped.class);
    });

    return true;
  }

}
```

The actually problem is, when I call my Resource everything is fine and i can access my project instance, but in my tomcat catalina logs i am getting the following stacke trace:

```
22-Jul-2016 16:29:46.510 WARNING [pool-24-thread-1] org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.logErrors The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 failure has been detected in a code that does not run in an active Jersey Error scope.
WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not inside a request scope.
    at jersey.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.current(RequestScope.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:158)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:765)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getUnqualifiedService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:772)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.IterableProviderImpl.get(IterableProviderImpl.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory.getContainerRequest(AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.PathParamValueFactoryProvider$PathParamValueFactory.provide(PathParamValueFactoryProvider.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.ParamInjectionResolver.resolve(ParamInjectionResolver.java:134)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.dispose(FactoryCreator.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.dispose(SystemDescriptor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.remove(RequestScope.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.release(RequestScope.java:549)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:968)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:922)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.AbstractBaseResource.send(AbstractBaseResource.java:118)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.AbstractBaseResource.resume(AbstractBaseResource.java:165)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.catalog.CatalogsResource.handleGet(CatalogsResource.java:49)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.catalog.AbstractCatalogResource.lambda$asyncGetRequest$0(AbstractCatalogResource.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of de.moss.ems.rest.factory.ProjectFactory errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:246)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.dispose(FactoryCreator.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.dispose(SystemDescriptor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.remove(RequestScope.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.release(RequestScope.java:549)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:968)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:922)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.AbstractBaseResource.send(AbstractBaseResource.java:118)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.AbstractBaseResource.resume(AbstractBaseResource.java:165)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.catalog.CatalogsResource.handleGet(CatalogsResource.java:49)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.catalog.AbstractCatalogResource.lambda$asyncGetRequest$0(AbstractCatalogResource.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on de.moss.ems.rest.factory.ProjectFactory
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:386)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.PerLookupContext.findOrCreate(PerLookupContext.java:70)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.FactoryCreator.dispose(FactoryCreator.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.dispose(SystemDescriptor.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.remove(RequestScope.java:532)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope$Instance.release(RequestScope.java:549)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:968)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder.resume(ServerRuntime.java:922)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.AbstractBaseResource.send(AbstractBaseResource.java:118)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.AbstractBaseResource.resume(AbstractBaseResource.java:165)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.catalog.CatalogsResource.handleGet(CatalogsResource.java:49)
    at de.moss.ems.rest.resource.catalog.AbstractCatalogResource.lambda$asyncGetRequest$0(AbstractCatalogResource.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas how I can solve this warnings?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Jersey to me, you should probably report it here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I reported this error here:

https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-3141

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using HK2's `org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup` Annotation instead of Jerseys `org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped` Annotation in my AbstractBinder class when I bind my factory to my interface.

```
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.PerLookup;

@Provider
public class ProjectFeature implements Feature {

  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {

    context.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
      bindFactory(ProjectFactory.class)
          .to(Project.class)
          .proxy(false)
          .proxyForSameScope(true)
          .in(PerLookup.class);
    });

    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround this bug by injecting `Factory` instead of the direct class. I also tested with `HttpServletRequest` injection and it works as well. However no `@PathParam` or any other smart annotation worked for me, so most likely you will have to workaround their usage.

My old code:

```
@Inject
public void setContext(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public SomeInfo provide() {
    return (SomeInfo) context.getProperty(SOME_KEY);
}
```

My new code:

```
@Inject
public void setContext(Factory<ContainerRequestContext> contextFactory) {
    this.contextFactory = contextFactory;
}

@Override
public SomeInfo provide() {
    ContainerRequestContext ctx = contextFactory.provide();
    try {
        return (SomeInfo) ctx.getProperty(SOME_KEY);
    } finally {
        contextFactory.dispose(ctx);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have a syntax error in one of your methods in the class you cannot "import" with Jersey, for me this was the case. I had two unclosed pluses in a string.